# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan x}{x} \log{\left(\frac{ 1+ x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, harmonic-numbers

> How to evaluate $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan x}{x} \log{\left(\frac{1+ x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)}\mathrm dx$$

I tried to integrate by parts, but no way so far, help me, thanks.

Comment: Utilizing $x\mapsto\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ allows to extract $\frac{\mathrm G}2\log2$. Again applying $x\mapsto\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ then yields to something of the form $$\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(x)}x\log(1+x^2)\mathrm dx$$ which can be further simplified via IBP. Essentially this reduces the problem to finding $$\int_0^1\frac x{1+x^2}\operatorname{Ti}_2(x)\mathrm dx$$ but I do not know how to continued from hereon.

Comment: Alternatively one can find an anti-derivative of $\frac{\log(1+x^2)}x$ using polylogarithms which boils down to finding $$\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-x^2)}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx=\int_0^\frac\pi4\operatorname{Li}_2(-\tan^2(x))\mathrm dx$$ and I'm almost entirely sure that I have seen something similiar to the latter one here on MSE before.

Comment: Mathematica can do mrtaurho's integral.  Constants are well-known, except for Li$_3((1+i)/2)).$

Comment: Integral is \begin{align}2\Im\left(\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)\right)+\text{G}\ln 2-\frac{3}{64}\pi^3-\frac{1}{16}\pi\ln^2 2\end{align}

Comment: @FofX It seems like all of the other responses on this webpage involve sophisticated mathematics.  I would be very interested in knowing the **context** of the problem.  Is this problem from a book or a class?  If so, what theorems or preliminary (solved) problems do you think might be pertinent to this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3006106/an-amm-like-integral-int-01-frac-arctan-xx-ln-frac1x231x2dx/3007623#3007623) we have that $$\frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan x \ln(1+x^2)}{x} dx =\frac13 \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan x \ln(1+x)}{x}dx$$
$$\Rightarrow I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan x}{x} \ln{\left(\frac{1+ x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)} dx=\frac23 \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan x \ln(1+x)}{x}  dx$$
I have encountered this integral too last year and asked it on [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1758111p11491099), you can take a look at **Knas** solution from there, giving:
$$I=\begin{align}2\Im\left(\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)\right)+\text{G}\ln 2-\frac{3}{64}\pi^3-\frac{1}{16}\pi\ln^2 2\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for your beautyful answer!

Answer (score 4):

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3006106/an-amm-like-integral-int-01-frac-arctan-xx-ln-frac1x231x2dx/3007623#3007623) , we have $\ \displaystyle \ 3\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln(1+x^2)}{x}\ dx-2\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln(1+x)}{x}\ dx=0$

or $\ I=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan x}{x} \ln{\left(\frac{ 1+ x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)}\ dx=\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln(1+x^2)}{x}\ dx$

using $\ \displaystyle\arctan x\ln(1+x^2)=-2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n H_{2n}} {2n+1}x^{2n+1}$ ( proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3240779/prove-ln1x2-arctan-x-2-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1n-h-2n2n1x2n1)) , we get
\begin{align}
I&=-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n}}{2n+1}\int_0^1x^{2n}\ dx\\
&=-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n}}{(2n+1)^2}\\
&=-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2}+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}\\
&=-2\Im\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{i^nH_n}{n^2}+\frac{\pi^3}{16}
\end{align}
using the generating function with $x=i$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^nH_n}{n^2}=\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)+\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)+\frac12\ln x\ln^2(1-x)+\zeta(3)$$
we get $\qquad\displaystyle\Im\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{i^nHn}{n^2}=-\frac{\pi}{16}\ln^22-\frac12G\ln2-\Im\operatorname{Li}_3(1-i)$

Plugging this result, we get $\quad\boxed{\displaystyle I=\frac{\pi^3}{16}+\frac{\pi}{8}\ln^22+G\ln2+2\Im\operatorname{Li}_3(1-i)}$

Answer (score 1):

different approach to evaluate $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan x\ln(1+x)}{x}\ dx$ :

from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3050696/proving-that-int-01-frac-arctan-xx-ln-left-frac1x21-x2-rightd/3204668#3204668) , we have $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln(1+x^2)}{x}\ dx-2\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln(1-x)}{x}\ dx=\frac{\pi^3}{16}\tag{1}$

and from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3006106/an-amm-like-integral-int-01-frac-arctan-xx-ln-frac1x231x2dx/3007623#3007623) , we have $\displaystyle \ 3\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln(1+x^2)}{x}\ dx-2\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln(1+x)}{x}\ dx=0\tag{2}$

by combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we obtain that $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln(1+x)}{x}\ dx=3\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln(1-x)}{x}\ dx+\frac{3\pi^3}{32}\tag{3}$

we have
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan x\ln(1-x)}{x}\ dx&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\int_0^1 x^{2n}\ln(1-x)\ dx\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2}=-\text{Im}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{i^nH_n}{n^2}\\
\end{align}
and using the generating function with $\ x=i$ $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^nH_n}{n^2}=\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)+\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)+\frac12\ln x\ln^2(1-x)+\zeta(3)$$
we get $\ \displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan x\ln(1-x)}{x}\ dx=\frac{\pi}{16}\ln^22+\frac12G\ln2+\text{Im}\operatorname{Li}_3(1-i)\tag{4}$

plugging $(4)$ in $(3)$, we get $$\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan x\ln(1+x)}{x}\ dx=\frac{3\pi^3}{32}+\frac{3\pi}{16}\ln^22+\frac32G\ln2+3\text{Im}\operatorname{Li}_3(1-i)$$