# Evaluate $\int _0^1\frac{\ln x\ln (1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\:dx$ without trigonometric and complex functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Earlier, I posted the sum evaluation that has the following integral representation.

$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^kH_k}{\left(2k+1\right)^2}=\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(x\right)\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2}\:\mathrm{d}x$$
Ali Shather managed to prove [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917154/looking-for-closed-forms-of-int-0-pi-4-ln2-sin-x-dx-and-int-0-pi-4/3211825#3211825)
$$\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(x\right)\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2}\:\mathrm{d}x=\frac3{32}\pi^3+\frac{\pi}8\ln^22-\ln2~G-2\text{Im}\operatorname{Li_3}(1+i)$$
which relies on trigonometric substitutions as well as complex methods.

**Question**:
Can this integral be evaluated without the trig functions? and is it possible to evaluate it without complex methods?

I tried using certain substitutions, but ended up with similar or even harder integrals. I'm not sure how to approach this.

Comment: Do you allow power series methods?

Comment: Sure, as long your methods dont make use of trigonometric functions and if possible avoid complex methods.

Comment: I thought I was doing something clever with power series, but just ended up getting the original sum. Time to try something else now.

Comment: Trying to avoid complex methods seems almost impossible, as the last term $\text{Im } \text{Li}_3(1+i)$ cannot be simplified anymore?

Comment: @TomChen i agree, at some point complex methods are involved but it would be nice to see an approach that doesnt necessarily depend on them, let's say i manage to end up with an expression having $\displaystyle \int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(1-x\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx\:\text{or}\:\:\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(1+x\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx$ these have to be done using complex methods but have been evaluated before in easy ways in this site.

Comment: @TomChen So I'm allowing to use the values of these kind of minor integrals is what I'm trying to say.

Comment: One can show that $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln\left(\frac{1+x^2}{2(1-x)^2}\right)}{1+x^2}dx=0$, then extract the desired integral out as $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3281210/evaluate-int-01-frac-ln-x-ln1-x1x2-dx).

Comment: Without trigonometric functions? The $\pi$ has to come from somewhere.

Answer (score 9):

A real-method based solution. Integrate

$\begin{align}
&\int_0^1\frac{\ln x \ln (1+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx \\
=& \int _0^1 \ln (1+x^2)\> d \left(\int_1^x \frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}dt\right)
\overset{IBP}=\int _0^1 \frac{-2x}{1+x^2}\left( \int_0^x \right. \overset{t=xs }{\left. \frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}dt+G\right)}dx \\
=& \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{-2x^2\ln (xs) }{(1+x^2)(1+x^2s^2)}dsdx -G\int_0^1 \frac{2x}{1+x^2}dx
\\
= &\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{-2x^2\ln x}{(1+x^2)(1+x^2s^2)}dsdx + \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{-2x^2\ln s }{(1+x^2)(1+x^2s^2)}dsdx -G\ln2 \\
= &-2\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln x\> \tan^{-1}x}{1+x^2}dx -2\int_0^1 \frac{s\ln s\> \tan^{-1}s}{1-s^2}ds  -G\ln2 \\
 =& -4\int_0^1 \underset{=J}{\frac{x\ln x\> \tan^{-1}x}{1-x^4}}dx -G\ln2=-4J -G\ln2
\end{align}$

and, similarly, integrate
\begin{align}\int _0^1\frac{\ln x \ln (1-x^2)}{1+x^2}dx 
&= \int _0^1 \ln (1-x^2)\> d \left(\int_1^x \frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}dt\right)
 = 4J-2G\ln2 +\frac{\pi^3}{16}
\end{align}
Then, eliminate the common term $J$
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2}dx
= -\int _0^1\frac{\ln x \ln (1-x^2)}{1+x^2}dx -3G\ln 2 +\frac{\pi^3}{16}\tag1 $$

Next, combine
\begin{align}
&\hspace{-3mm}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx
\overset{\text{split}(0,\infty)}= 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx
-2 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx+\frac{\pi^3}{16}\\
&\hspace{-3mm}\int_0^1 \underset{x\to\frac{1-x}{1+x}}{\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx}
= \hspace{-3mm}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx
-2 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx-2G\ln2+\frac{\pi^3}{16}\\
\end{align}
to get
$$\hspace{-5mm}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx
=\frac12\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx-\hspace{-3mm} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx -2G\ln2+\frac{\pi^3}{32}\tag2
$$
Also, per $ab = \frac12 (a^2 +b^2 -(a-b)^2)$
$$\hspace{-5mm}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx
=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2\frac x{1-x}}{1+x^2}dx + \frac{\pi^3}{32} \tag3
$$
Then, (2) + (3)
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1-x^2)}{1+x^2}dx 
=-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx -2G\ln2+\frac{\pi^3}{16} +\frac12 K \tag4$$
where $ \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx=2\text{Im}\>\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}2\right)$ and
\begin{align}
K =& \int_0^1 \underset{t=1-x}{\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1+x^2}}dx +\underset{t=1+x}{
\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x^2}}dx -\int_0^1\underset{t=\frac x{1-x}}{\frac{\ln^2\frac x{1-x}}{1+x^2}}dx \\
 =& \int_0^\infty {\frac{4t \ln^2 t}{4+t^4}}dt
 \overset{t^2\to 2t}= \frac{\pi}{8}\ln^22+\frac{\pi^3}{32}
\end{align}

Plug into (4) and then into (1) to obtain
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx  =2\text{Im}\>\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}2\right) -G\ln2
-\frac{\pi}{16}\ln^22-\frac{\pi^3}{64}$$

Comment: The harder part is to prove that $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx=2\text{Im}\>\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}2\right)$

Comment: It follows directly from the integral definition of $\text{Li}_3(a)$ $$\text{Li}_3(a)=  \frac 12\int_0^1 \frac{a\ln^2t}{1-at}dt = \frac 12 \int_0^1 \frac{a\ln^2 (1-x)}{1-a+ax}dx$$