# Find close form for $\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)\log(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, polylogarithm

I am trying to find a closed form for the integral,$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)\log(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx$$
I tried using the sub, $x=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ but it was to no avail. I also tried the trig sub, $x=\tan(y)$ but was stuck with the integral, $$\int_0^{\pi/4} \log^2(\sin(y))dy$$
I need help with any of the two integrals.

Comment: *Mathematica* gives for the first integral:  $$\frac{1}{192} \left(-192 C \log (2)+2 i \left(-192
   \text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)+105 \zeta (3)+4 \log ^3(2)\right)-3
   \pi ^3-12 \pi  \log ^2(2)-2 i \pi ^2 \log (32)\right)$$

Comment: The first and second integrals are not equivalent; applying the transformation $x=\tan(y)$ to the first integral produces $I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \log(\tan(y)) \log(\sec^2(y))dy$

Comment: @failedentertainment $$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} log(tan(y))log(sec^2(y))dy=-2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} log(sin(y))log(cos(y))dy -2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} log^2(cos(y))dy$$ Using the Identity,$-2ab=(a-b)^2-a^2-b^2$ and setitng $y=\frac{\pi}{2} - y$   We would have the integral i mentioned in the question.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Wow

Comment: This integral is already asked and answered  here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/917154/432085

Comment: [Evaluate $\int _0^1\frac{\ln x\ln (1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\:dx$ without trigonometric and complex functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3870233/686284)

Comment: @AliShadhar Thank you very much Prof.

Comment: @Quanto Thank you very much sir. I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 6):

\begin{gather*}
\int_0^1\frac{\ln^{2a}(x)\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x\\
=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^{2a}(x)\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x-\underbrace{\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln^{2a}(x)\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x}_{x\to 1/x}\\
=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^{2a}(x)\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^{2a}(x)\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x\\
+2\int_0^1\frac{\ln^{2a+1}(x)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x\\
\left\{\text{add $\int_0^1\frac{\ln^{2a}(x)\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x$ to both sides then divide by 2}\right\}\\
=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^{2a}(x)\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^1\frac{\ln^{2a+1}(x)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x
\end{gather*}
By the definition of Dirichlet beta function, the second integral is

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^{2a+1}(x)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x=-(2a+1)!\beta(2a+2).$$

To get the first integral, we need following result

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^{2a}(x)\ln(1+x)}{\sqrt{x}(1+x)}\mathrm{d}x$$
$$=2{\pi^{2a+1}}\ln2|E_{2a}|+(2a)!{\pi^{2a+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{a} \frac{|E_{2a-2k}|}{(2a-2k)!}{\pi^{-2k}}(2^{2k+1}-1)\zeta(2k+1)$$

which was found by @user178256 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4140772) and I managed to provide a rigorous proof:

we follow the same technique as in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3538399). Replace $n$ by $n-m$ in the beta function in:
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{m-1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}}\mathrm{d}x=\operatorname{B}(m,n)=\frac{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(m+n)},
\end{equation*}
we get
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{m-1}}{(1+x)^{n}}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(n-m)}{\Gamma(n)}.
\end{equation*}
Differentiate $2a$ times with respect to $m$  and once with respect to $n$,
\begin{equation*}
\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\ln^{2a}(x)x^{m-1}\ln(1+x)}{(1+x)^n}\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{\partial^{2a}}{\partial m^{2a}} \frac{\partial}{\partial n}\frac{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(n-m)}{\Gamma(n)}.
\end{equation*}

Now take the limit on both sides letting $m\to 1/2$ and $n\to1$,

\begin{gather*}
\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\ln^{2a}(x)\ln(1+x)}{\sqrt{x}(1+x)}\mathrm{d}x=-\lim_{\substack{m\to 1/2\\n\to 1}}\frac{\partial^{2a}}{\partial m^{2a}} \operatorname{\Gamma}(m)\frac{\partial}{\partial n} \frac{\operatorname{\Gamma}(n-m)}{\operatorname{\Gamma}(n)}\\
\{\text{use $\Gamma'(x)=\Gamma(x)\psi(x)$}\}\\
=-\lim_{m\to 1/2}\frac{\partial^{2a}}{\partial m^{2a}} \Gamma(m)\left(\lim_{n\to 1}\frac{\Gamma(n-m)[{\psi}(n-m) -\psi(n)]}{\Gamma(n)}\right)\\
\{\text{use $\psi(1)=-\gamma$ }\}\\
=-\lim_{m\to 1/2 }\frac{\partial^{2a}}{\partial m^{2a}} \Gamma(m)\Gamma(1-m)[\psi(1-m) + \gamma]\\
\left\{\text{use  $\Gamma(m)\Gamma(1-m)=\pi \csc(m\pi)$ }\right\}\\
=-\pi\lim_{m\to \frac12 }\frac{d^{2a}}{dm^{2a}}\csc(m\pi)\, (\psi(1-m)+\gamma).\\
\left\{\text{use $\frac{d^a}{dm^a}(f*g)=\sum_{k=0}^a \binom{a}{k} \frac{d^{a-k}}{dm^{a-k}} f*\frac{d^k}{dm^k}g$}\right\}\\
=-\pi\sum_{k=0}^{2a} \binom{2a}{k}\lim_{m\to \frac12}\frac{d^{2a-k}}{dm^{2a-k}} \csc(m\pi) \lim_{m\to \frac12}\frac{d^{k}}{dm^k} (\psi(1-m)+\gamma)\\
\left\{\text{use $\sum_{k=0}^{2a}f(k)=\sum_{k=0}^a f(2k+1)+\sum_{k=0}^a f(2k)$}\right\}\\
=-\pi\sum_{k=0}^{a} \binom{2a}{2k+1}\lim_{m\to \frac12}\frac{d^{2a-2k-1}}{dm^{2a-2k-1}} \csc(m\pi)\, \lim_{m\to \frac12}\frac{d^{2k+1}}{dm^{2k+1}} (\psi(1-m)+\gamma)\\
=-\pi\sum_{k=0}^{a} \binom{2a}{2k}\lim_{m\to \frac12}\frac{d^{2a-2k}}{dm^{2a-2k}} \csc(m\pi)\, \lim_{m\to \frac12}\frac{d^{2k}}{dm^{2k}} (\psi(1-m)+\gamma)\\
\left\{\text{ignore first sum since $\lim_{m\to \frac12}\frac{d^{a}}{dm^{a}}\csc(m\pi)=0$ for odd $a$}\right\}\\
=-\pi\sum_{k=0}^{a} \binom{2a}{2k}|E_{2a-2k}|\pi^{2a-2k}\, \lim_{m\to \frac12}\frac{d^{2k}}{dm^{2k}} (\psi(1-m)+\gamma)\\
\{\text{separate the first term using $\psi(1/2)+\gamma=-2\ln(2)$}\}\\
=2\ln(2)|E_{2a}|\pi^{2a+1}\\
-\pi\sum_{k=1}^{a} \binom{2a}{2k}|E_{2a-2k}|\pi^{2a-2k}\, \lim_{m\to \frac12}\frac{d^{2k}}{dm^{2k}} (\psi(1-m)+\gamma)\\
\{\text{use the definition of the polygamma function}\}\\
=2\ln(2)|E_{2a}|\pi^{2a+1}\\
-\pi\sum_{k=1}^{a} \binom{2a}{2k}|E_{2a-2k}|\pi^{2a-2k} \psi^{(2k)}\left(\frac12\right)\\
=2\ln(2)|E_{2a}|\pi^{2a+1}\\
+\pi\sum_{k=1}^{a} \binom{2a}{2k}|E_{2a-2k}|\pi^{2a-2k}\, (2k)!(2^{2k+1}-1)\zeta(2k+1),
\end{gather*}

Setting $\sqrt{x}=y$ in the integral gives
\begin{equation*}
\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\ln^{2a}(x)\ln(1+x)}{\sqrt{x}(1+x)}\mathrm{d}x=2^{2a+1}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^{2a}(y)\ln(1+y^2)}{1+y^2}\mathrm{d}y. 
\end{equation*}

Thus,

\begin{gather}
\int_0^1\frac{\ln^{2a}(x)\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x=-(2a+1)!\beta(2a+2)+\ln(2)|E_{2a}|\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2a+1}\nonumber\\
+\frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2a+1}}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{a} \binom{2a}{2k}(2k)!|E_{2a-2k}|\pi^{-2k}(2^{2k+1}-1)\zeta(2k+1).
\end{gather}

---

Used results:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{z\to \frac12}\frac{d^{2a}}{dz^{2a}}\csc(z\pi)=|E_{2a}|\pi^{2a}
\end{equation}
where $E_r$ is the Euler number.

\begin{equation}
\psi^{(a)}\left(\frac12\right)=(-1)^{a}a!(1-2^{a+1})\zeta(a+1). 
\end{equation}

---

Answer (score 2):

Using Feynman's trick $$I(a)=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)\log(1+ax^2)}{1+x^2}dx$$
$$I'(a)=\int_0^1 \frac{x^2 \log (x)}{\left(x^2+1\right) \left(a x^2+1\right)} \,dx$$
$$I'(a)=\frac{C}{1-a}-\frac{i \left(\text{Li}_2\left(i \sqrt{a}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(-i
   \sqrt{a}\right)\right)}{2 (a-1) \sqrt{a}}$$ which, integrated for $a$ between $0$ and $1$, leads to what @David G. Stork gave in comments.

Now, for an *approximation*, you could use the value of $I'(a)$ and its derivatives at the boudaries and obtain
$$I'(0)=C-1\qquad \qquad I'(1)=\frac{\pi }{8}-\frac{C}{2}$$
$$I''(0)=C-\frac{8}{9}\qquad \qquad I''(1)=\frac{3 C}{8}+\frac{1}{16}-\frac{\pi }{8}$$
$$I'''(0)=2 C-\frac{418}{225}\qquad \qquad I'''(1)=-\frac{5 C}{8}-\frac{3}{16}+\frac{23 \pi }{96}$$ and build the polynomial
$$I'(a)=\sum_{n=1}^5 b_n \,a^n$$
$$(C-1)+ \left(C-\frac{8}{9}\right)a+ \left(C-\frac{209}{225}\right)a^2+\frac{
   (-123900 C+85326+8975 \pi )}{4800}a^3+$$ $$\frac{ (264600 C-174764-21525 \pi
   )}{7200}a^4+\frac{ (-207900 C+134126+17925 \pi )}{14400}a^5$$ which, integrated, leads to
$$I(1)=\frac{311 C}{960}-\frac{264463}{432000}+\frac{887 \pi }{11520}=-0.0735565$$ to be compared to the value of $-0.0735540$ given by @David G. Stork' expression.

This could be much improved increasing the degree of the polynomial approximant.

For example, pushing the expansion to degree $9$ would give
$$I(1)=\frac{27697 C}{80640}-\frac{10258077467}{16003008000}+\frac{222527 \pi }{2764800}=-0.0735539700$$ to be compared to the exact
$-0.0735539567$

This is a kind of two point Taylor series.