# How to show $\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+x^2}{2}\right)}{1+x^2}dx=\ln(2)G$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, alternative-proof, polylogarithm

I am trying to prove that
$$\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+x^2}{2}\right)}{1+x^2}dx=\ln(2)G,$$
where $G$ is the Catalan constant and $\operatorname{Li}_2(x)$ is the dilogarithm function, which is proposed by my friend Sujeethan Balendran and solved in two methods by my friend Cornel Valean in his second book "*More (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series*" page 345. I want to try it differently using as less results and relations as possible and here is my attempt:

---

$$\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+x^2}{2}\right)}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}\left(\int_0^1\frac{-\frac{1+x^2}{2}\ln(y)}{1-\frac{1+x^2}{2}y}dy\right)dx$$

$$=\int_0^1 \ln(y)\left(\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)y-2}\right)dy$$

$$=\int_0^1\ln(y)\left(\frac{1}{y}\sqrt{\frac{y}{y-2}}\arctan \sqrt{\frac{y}{y-2}}\right)dy\quad \text{let}
\quad\sqrt{\frac{y}{y-2}}=ix$$

$$=\int_0^1\frac{-2\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\ln\left(\frac{2x^2}{1+x^2}\right)}{1+x^2}dx$$

$$=\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\ln\left(\frac{2x^2}{1+x^2}\right)}{1+x^2}dx\quad \text{let}
\quad\frac{1-x}{1+x}\to x$$

$$=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)\ln\left(\frac{(1-x)^2}{1+x^2}\right)}{1+x^2}dx$$

$$=2\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx$$

These two integrals are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3281259) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3211825) respectively and combining them gives $\ln(2)G.$

---

**Question**: Is there an elegant way to prove $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)\ln\left(\frac{(1-x)^2}{1+x^2}\right)}{1+x^2}dx=\ln(2)G$ without breaking the integrand or is there a different way to evaluate $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+x^2}{2}\right)}{1+x^2}dx$?

Thank you,

Comment: Probably help if you would tell us what $G$ stands for.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson its Catalan constant.

Comment: Good. And, what is Catalan's constant?

Comment: @GerryMyerson its here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant

Comment: If you want to know something, Ali, should you make it hard for people to help you, or should you make it easier? Please, put the definition of Catalan's constant in the body of your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution by Sujeethan Balendran:

By the change of variable $x=\tan\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)$, we have
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)dx=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\tan\frac{x}{2}\right)\ln\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)dx$$

use the Fourier series of $\ln(\tan x)$

$$=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\tan\frac{x}{2}\right)\left(2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\sin((2n-1)x)}{2n-1}\right)dx$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}\left(\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin((2n-1)x)\ln\left(\tan\frac{x}{2}\right)dx\right)$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}\left(\int_0^{\pi/2} d\left(\frac{1-\cos((2n-1)x)}{2n-1}\right)\ln\left(\tan\frac{x}{2}\right)dx\right)$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}\left( \frac{1-\cos((2n-1)x)}{2n-1}\ln\left(\tan\frac{x}{2}\right)\bigg|_0^{\pi/2}-2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{(2n-1)x}{2}\right)}{(2n-1)\sin x}dx\right)$$

$$=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n-1)^2} \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{(2n-1)x}{2}\right)}{\sin x}dx$$

shift the index then separate the first term

$$=-2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\sin x}dx+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n+1)^2} \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{(2n+1)x}{2}\right)}{\sin x}dx$$

$$=-\ln(2)+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n+1)^2} \left(\frac{H_n+\overline{H}_n+\ln(2)}{2}\right)$$

$$=-\ln(2)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n+1)^2} \left(H_n+\overline{H}_n\right)+\ln(2)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n+1)^2}$$

$$=\ln(2)\left(-1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n+1)^2}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1} \left(H_n+\overline{H}_n\right)\left(-\int_0^1 x^{2n}\ln(x)dx\right)$$

$$=\ln(2)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n+1)^2}-\int_0^1 \ln(x)\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}H_n x^{2n}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\overline{H}_n x^{2n}\right)dx$$

$$=-\ln(2)G-\int_0^1 \ln(x)\left(\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}-\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{1+x^2}\right)dx$$

$$=-\ln(2)G+\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}\ln\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right)dx$$

So we have

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)dx=-\ln(2)G+\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}\ln\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right)dx$$

or

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}\ln\left(\frac{(1-x)^2}{1+x^2}\right)dx=\ln(2)G$$

Note: $\overline{H}_n$ is defined as $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}k$

Comment: thanks brother

Comment: @SSS welcome my friend

Comment: That answer is too non-trivial, I admire your friend's genius. I added the definition of the alternating harmonic numbers, is that okay?

Comment: @KamalSaleh of course that's fine and thank you. sorry to reply late just saw your comment.

Answer (score 6):

Substitute $x=\tan t$ to rewrite the integral as

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln\frac{(1-x)^2}{1+x^2}}{1+x^2}\ dx
= 2\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\ln(\tan t)\ln(\cos t-\sin t)\ dt
$$
where the transformed integral is evaluated elementarily [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3866385/686284).

Comment: Thank you Quanto very nice proof but based on your steps, we are breaking the integrand.

Comment: @AliShadhar - Right, I did break up the integrand. I don’t know how to keep it in one piece. I guess my goal was to keep it elementary

Comment: Still very nice approach (+1)