# How to evaluate $\int_0 ^ 1 \frac{\ln (x)(1+\ln(x) +\ln(1-x))}{x^2+1}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I want to evaluate $$\int_0 ^ 1 \frac{\ln (x)(1+\ln(x) +\ln(1-x))}{x^2+1}dx$$.

This question is from RMM.

I tried to separate the integral into:

$$\begin{align*}
& \int_0 ^ 1 \frac{\ln (x)(1+\ln(x) +\ln(1-x))}{x^2+1}dx \\
&= \int_0 ^ 1 \frac{\ln (x)}{x^2+1}dx+\int_0 ^ 1 \frac{\ln^2 (x)}{x^2+1}dx + \int_0 ^ 1 \frac{\ln (x)\ln(1-x)}{x^2+1}dx \\
&= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln(\tan(x))dx+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln^2(\tan(x))dx+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(\tan(x))\ln(1-\tan(x)) dx
\end{align*}$$

I have tried all the integration methods that I know, but I couldn't reach any useful result.

Comment: The first one is negative Catalan constant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant.

Comment: You can use series to handle the first two integrals.

Comment: @xpaul what about the third one ?

Comment: When I have time I will work on it.

Comment: Maybe Fourier series will also work; at least for the first two integrals, try replacing$$\log(\tan x) = -2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\cos((4k-2)x)}{2k-1}$$

Comment: The first two integrals can be written as eta functions.

Comment: See also notebook [MSE_Q4832089](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/pfeifermaintal/Published/MSE_Q4832089.nb)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize $ 2\ln x\ln(1-x)
=\ln^2x+\ln^2(1-x)-\ln^2\frac x{1-x}$ to break up the integral as follows

\begin{align}
I=&\int_0 ^ 1 \frac{\ln x\ [1+\ln x+\ln(1-x)]}{x^2+1}dx\\
=& \int_0 ^ 1 \frac{\ln x}{x^2+1}dx
 + \frac32\int_0 ^ 1 \frac{\ln^2x}{x^2+1}dx\\
&\>\>\>\>\> + \frac12 \int_0 ^ 1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x^2+1}dx
 -\frac12 \int_0 ^ 1 \frac{\ln^2\frac x{1-x}}{x^2+1}dx
\end{align}
where the first three integrals are familiar $\int_0 ^ 1 \frac{\ln x}{x^2+1}dx=-G$
$$\int_0 ^ 1 \frac{\ln^2x}{x^2+1}dx=\frac{\pi^3}{16},
\>\>\>  \int_0 ^ 1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x^2+1}dx=2\Im{\text{Li}_3(\frac{1+i}2)}$$
and the last integral can be
further broken up as
\begin{align}
& \int_0 ^ 1 \frac{\ln^2\frac x{1-x}}{x^2+1}\overset{t= \frac x{1-x} }{dx}
=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2t}{t^2+2t +2}dt\\
=& \int_0^\infty \frac{t^2\ln^2t}{t^4+4}\overset{t\to\frac{\sqrt2}t}{dt}
-2 \int_0^\infty \frac{t\ln^2t}{t^4+4}\overset{t^2\to 2t}{dt}
+2 \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2t}{t^4+4}\overset{t\to\sqrt2 t}{dt} \\
=& -\frac{\ln^22}8\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{t^2+1}dt
-\frac18 \int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^2t}{t^2+1}dt \\
&\>\>\>\>\> -\frac{\ln^22}{2\sqrt2}\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{t^4+1}dt+ \sqrt2 \int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^2t}{t^4+1}dt\\
=& \ \frac{5\pi^3}{64}+\frac\pi{16}\ln^2 2
\end{align}
Substitute  above results into $I$ to obtain
$$
I
=-G +\frac{7\pi^3}{128}-\frac{\pi}{32}\ln^22
+ \Im{\text{Li}_3(\frac{1+i}2)}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Splitting the integrand into three and evaluating them one by one.
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x(1+\ln x+\ln (1-x))}{x^2+1} d x= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x^2+1} d x+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^2 x}{x^2+1} d x+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x \ln (1-x)}{x^2+1} d x
$$

---

As we know that $$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x^2+1} d x=-G$$

---

Considering \begin{aligned}
J(a) & =\int_0^1 \frac{x^a}{x^2+1} d x =\frac{1}{4}\left[\psi\left(\frac{a+3}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{a+1}{4}\right)\right]
\end{aligned}
Then $$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2x}{x^2+1}  =J^{\prime \prime}(0)=\frac{1}{64}\left[\psi^{\prime \prime}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)-\psi^{\prime \prime}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right]=\frac{\pi^3}{16}
$$

---

Using the result in [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3281210/732917),
$$\ \displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}\ dx=\frac{3\pi^3}{64}+\frac{\pi}{16}\ln^22-\Im\operatorname{Li}_3(1+i),$$
we can conclude that
$$
\boxed{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x(1+\ln x+\ln (1-x))}{x^2+1} d x =-G+\frac{7 \pi^3}{64}+\frac{\pi}{16} \ln ^2 2-\Im \operatorname{Li_3}(1+i)}
$$